# COUNTIFS with 2 different ranges and conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table from which I need to count the ammount of specific numbers.

The table is dynamic and can have between 1 to 25 columns where the numbers are and then a code that starts with either a letter, 1 or 2. It has multiple rows too.

What I need is to have formulas to count the ammount of each specific number range if the code starts with the correct character as shown in the example image:

[image: example]

I can't manage to join the condition of the first range being between 2 numbers and the second range starting with a specific character.

The formula should look somewhat like this (count numbers between 200 and 299 with the code starting with 2):

`=COUNTIFS(Table[[1]:[4]];">=200";Table[[1]:[4]];"<=299";Table[code];"2*")`

```
letter  1   2       letter  1   2
100-199 200-299 200-299     2   1   1
300-399 400-499 400-499     3   3   3
500-599 600-699         2   2
700-799             2

1   2   3   4   code
139 307 165     B01
430             2CTE
581 703         PDC
312 354 528 746 GVM7
600 477         1OMC
299 425 413     2LP
231 666 420 433 1MLTQ
```

Comment: use left(value,1) to get the start with. Use Find and mid and len and right/left  to find the "-" and extract the number to the left for >= and the number to the right to get <= Stick that into Countifs

Comment: @QHarr Can you elaborate it a bit more? I'm confused.

Comment: And please don't post images of data without a supporting insert of actual data we can copy and paste. I don't want to have to type it out. Others might.

Comment: @QHarr Edited if that helps.

Comment: Left(code,1) will give you what the code bit starts with. You would compare that with wherever you are specifiying the start number/string.

Comment: the problem is the letter, you may need to shift to a SUMPRODUCT.

Comment: @QHarr The first table (top left) is just to explain what the second (top  right) wants. The formulas go to the second one.

Comment: What does letter 2, 3 etc mean in the top right? You want to match on the 2nd or 3rd letter of the code?

Comment: @QHarr  That's the results I want from the formulas. The top left table is just to help explain the question.

Comment: @QHarr For example, there's 2 numbers between 100-199 which have the code starting with a letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put this in F3 then copy over and down:

```
=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT((Table[[1]:[4]]>=--LEFT(B3,3))*(Table[[1]:[4]]<=--RIGHT(B3,3))*(((ISNUMBER(F$2))*(LEFT(Table[[code]:[code]])=F$2&""))+((NOT(ISNUMBER(F$2)))*(NOT(ISNUMBER(LEFT(Table[[code]:[code]]))))))),"")
```

[image]

---

As per your comments to get everything between 400 and 499 and starts with 2:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Table[[1]:[4]]>=400)*(Table[[1]:[4]]<=499)*(LEFT(Table[[code]:[code]])="2"))
```

Comment: Couldn't get that to work but I think I need to explain better too. The top left table is a visual explanation of what the real table (topright) uses as condition to count. I know how to make the formulas to count between two numbers what I can't figure out is how to add the extra condition of checking the code's first letter.

Comment: So to make it easier to understand lets pretend there's only the bottom table and the columns with the numbers is x and the column with the codes is y. How can I count the numbers on x that are between 400 and 499 and which the code starts with a 2?